# ListBox with multiple captured images windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, image-gallery, listboxitem

Does anyone know how to make a listbox with multiple images. I want to be able to capture an image and then display on the screen, then capture another and display after the first one and so on. It is basically images gallery page that I want to create. I would like to store them somewhere on the phone, so they can be retrieved when the application runs again.

So it should be something like in the picture: http://blog.xamarin.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/wp2.png

Thank you in advance, I have been doing researches about it but can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that is fairly easy. You use a ListBox set the ItemsPanel to a WrapPanel, and either bind ItemsSource to a ObservableCollection (or List/Array, but ObservableCollection is better suited for Bindings).

There are multible ways to do it
Lets take the easiest approach. In xaml you define your ListBox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listbox">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>

            <toolkit:WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="5"
                  Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}"
                  Height="180"
                  Width="180">
                <Image Source="{Binding}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In your code behind, you can load the images with something like this:

```
ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> images = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();
List<String> bitmapuris = ....
using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    foreach(var bitmapuri in bitmapuris)
    {
        System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bitmap = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();

        if (isoStore.FileExists(bitmapuri))
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = isoStore.OpenFile(bitmapuri, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
            {
                bitmap.CreateOptions = System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapCreateOptions.BackgroundCreation;
                bitmap.SetSource(stream);
            }
        }
        images.Add(bitmap);
    }
}
listbox.ItemsSource = images;
```

With bitmapuris being a List with all of your saved images urls.

Thats basicly what I'm using in some of my apps (though I use ViewModels and Bindings and don't set ItemsSource manually)

Hope this helps

edit:
On how to capture and save images you can read this article:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahakgupta/capture-save-and-edit-image-in-windows-phone-7/

I would save the Images in a specific folder i.e. "/Images/". That way you can load all images you previously captured on you app start with the code I posted above with `List<String> bitmapuris` set with this method:

```
List<String> getFiles(String folderpath)
{
    IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    return storage.GetFileNames(folderpath).ToList();
}
```

like this `List<String> bitmapuris = getFiles("/Images/*");`

and when you captured an image you can simple add your image to your ListBox this way:

```
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bitmap = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
bitmap.CreateOptions = System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapCreateOptions.BackgroundCreation;
bitmap.SetSource(myimagestream);
images.Add(bitmap);
```

providing images is the `ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>` you set as an ItemsSource to your ListBox.

This is now almost your fully working app, when compined with the link from above.

Comment: @Stefan.. Thank you, that gave me a rough idea what I am suppose to to, but if there is any example app, or full source code, it will be much helpful, thanks once again

Comment: @Stefan.. I am quite happy with your xaml code, but when it comes to its actual code, I think I am bit frustrating. All I want to do is have a page, which allows me to capture images and save them into isolated storage, then retrieve same image and display it on the page, and so on. So I want the page to have the ability to store many captured pictures as a list. Thanks for the help anyways, hope you can help me even further

Comment: @Jordan See my edit, now you basicly only need to copy all the code and you have your app

Comment: @Stefan.. Thank you so much for helping me. I have copied your code and placed on the page I wanted, and it works perfectly fin, the only thing it doesn't do is save the images onto the isolated storage, I have to figure out how to do that, thanks once again

Comment: @Jordan Look at the link in my answer, there is a method to save an image. You can just take that and you'd only have to change one line of code (Here is the link again: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahakgupta/capture-save-and-edit-image-in-windows-phone-7/). Please mark the answer as answered if that helped you.

Comment: @Stefan.. Thanks once again, I had a look in the link you have posted here. It is very useful, now I understand the procedure to save the images, but as always I came across something I can't get my head round to. I don't know how to save an image with a computer generated name or probably the actual names used by captured pictures. As I said I will be adding a large number of images, so I want the computer to give it a name. If you have any ideas please share. Thanks very much once again, you are being very useful. I have also marked your answer with a green tick :)